# Can Azure Application Insights Kusto queries obtain the user's current time zone?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

We have a chart that restricts details to "today". Today means something different depending on the viewer's time zone: right now for me (in Adelaide, AUS) today means everything in the last 15 hours but for someone in the UK it only means everything in the last 6.5 hours. Is there any way of retrieving the client's time zone in a Kusto query in Application Insights?

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings of the query console:
[image]

Change timezone to "Local Time" (default is UTC)
[image]